# Concatenate object and key value and get the length

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my sample data in which I am trying to access the key and get length, 'xxxxxx20160929' key is dynamic:

```
"resultData": [{
    "a": "124",
    "b": "0",
    "c": "0",
    "d": {
        "e": "6",
        "f": "en",
        "xxxxxx20160929": [{
            "ID": "yyyyyyyy"
        },
        {
            "ID": "fffff"
        }
     ]
    }
}]
```

Below is the code I have tried:

```
var m = 1;
var schedule = [];
// looping to get key value 'xxxxxx20160929' 
$.each(response.resultData['0'].d, function(key, value) {
    if (m == 3) {
        //got value 'xxxxxx20160929'   
        schedule.push(key);
        //trying to check the length of 'xxxx20160929'     
        console.log(response.resultData['0'].d.key.length);
    }
    m++;
});
```

My expected output is 2, because 'xxxxxx20160929' is looping 2 times.

Comment: I am confused. Can you explain what is the actual result you are getting? because I can't see how you'd get `2`. It's either `1`, `3`, or more, it depends on what is the number you are trying to get.

Comment: and how does `m==3`?

Comment: where is fltSchedule key in your json?

Comment: updated pls check

Comment: @vlaz, epascarello :  inside d key 3 keys are there e,f, xxxxxx20160929.  So while looping m==3 is xxxxxx20160929. I want 'xxxxxx20160929' value dynamically and length of 'xxxxxx20160929'

Comment: So is that the length of the _string_ `xxxxxx20160929` or the length of the _value_ associated with that key or...what? Because the string is clearly longer than 2 characters, and the value is an array clearly only holding 1 element. I don't know where the number 2 would be coming from. Also, properties in an object do NOT have an order, looping through them until your counter reaches some number is completely meaningless. Browsers _usually_ return the keys in the same order every tine but you should not rely on that.

Comment: your expected output should 1 not 2 as xxxxxx20160929 is array of one object

Comment: @vlaz, epascarello : Updated above pls check

Comment: your question is f****** confusing man.

Comment: @suraj99934 : I have updated my json pls check once, I want 'xxxxxx20160929' length(looping length) and 'xxxxxx20160929' is dynamic. Also want the dynamic key value 'xxxxxx20160929'

Comment: do this
resultData[0].d[Object.keys(resultData[0].d)[2]].length

Comment: `console.log(key.length)` will show the length of the key.

Comment: What's the point of `if(m == 3)`? The order of properties in an object is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the interesting dynamic key can be found *ALWAYS* at a fixed position in the **d** object.  This is *VERY* brittle.  If there is a better way to signal for the key (such as it always starts with "xxxxxx" then I'll update.

**UPDATE:**
I altered the test for interesting key to be one for a string that ends in 8 digits (that could be your date) per your comment with an example key of **NEWYORKBOMDEL20160929**

```js
var data = {
  "resultData": [
    {
      "a": "124",
      "b": "0",
      "c": "0",
      "d": {
          "e": "6",
          "f": "en",
          "xxxxxx20160929": [
            {"ID": "yyyyyyyy" },
            {"ID": "fffff"}
         ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

data.resultData.forEach(function(item){
  var _key = Object
               .keys(item.d)
               .filter(function(x){ return /\d{8}$/.test(x); })[0];

  var _value = item.d[_key];
  
  console.log("Key: " + _key);
  console.log("Children: " + _value.length);
  
  _value.forEach(function(child){
    var _childKey = Object.keys(child)[0];
    var _childValue = child[_childKey];

    console.log("   Key: \"" + _childKey + "\" Value: \"" + _childValue + "\"");
  });

});
```

Comment: @john: now how can i get 'ID' value dynamically

Comment: I can update the example but I need to know how to determine when the key is the interesting key.  Is it a key that starts with a number, or a key that starts with "xxxxxx"?  How do you as a person looking at the data, know what key is the interesting one?

Comment: xxxxxx is a combination of city.dateofjourney, eg : NEWYORKBOMDEL20160929.

Comment: @JOHN your update is fine, now i want  "ID"  value..... how can  i get this

Comment: I updated the demo to print the child keys and values

Answer (score 0):

to get number ob items in your object, you can't use "length" its for arrays, for an object you can use

`Object.keys(response.resultData['0'].d).length`

or

`Object.keys(response.resultData['0'].d[key]).length`

UDP:

just got your question :)

to access a dynamic object key use [] to access them

```
d[key]
```

Comment: can u give fiddle link for above json, I have tried like here response.resultData['0'].d.keys(key).length, giving undefined error

Comment: @sivashanker just updated my answer with a code example

Comment: @sivashanker also in your code you use "key" in dot notation, its not gonna work... use it like this 'response.resultData['0'].d[key]'

Comment: I want 'xxxxxx20160929' length(looping length) and 'xxxxxx20160929' is dynamic. Also want the dynamic key value 'xxxxxx20160929'

Comment: @sivashanker use d[key] instead of d.key

Comment: @Fribu Please replace your original answer if it was incorrect (instead of just appending to it), much easier to see the actual answer that way. Also, the solution can actually be simplified to `value.length` instead of `response.resultData['0'].d[key].length`.

Answer (score 0):

Do following, you dont have to wrte so much code

```
resultData[0].d[Object.keys(resultData[0].d)[2]].length
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the key with a particular length, you can do:

```
$.each(response.resultData['0'].d, function(key, value) {
    if (key.length == 14) {
        schedule.push(key);
        console.log(key, value);
    }
    m++;
});
```